# How to pass data from javascript to php in same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to know how I can pass data from my script javascript to my php code to use the data into a query
I tried many things but it didn't work for me 
So this is my script to upload files from input type: file then i get the url in downloadURL variable

```
        var downloadURL;
           ...

          uploadTask.on('state_changed',function(snapshot){

            },function(error){

            },function(){

                downloadURL=uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                alert(downloadURL);

             });
```

Now I want to pass `downloadURL` to my php so I can use it .
I also tried Ajax to do this task but it didn't work or the code that I used is false
Ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '', //same page
    data: downloadURL ,
    success: function(data)
    {
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
Php code :

```
<?php 

    $user=$_POST['downloadURL'];

    echo $user;  
?>
```

Just a normal echo to test if data is Posted or not

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_? any errors?

Comment: When I echo the result it said undefined

Comment: You had no url for your ajax request. Give url to ajax request and will work

Comment: Also from your php you should return any value to ajax

Comment: @SiderTopalov why should I return any value ? and how to do it

Comment: Provide your php code and i will help you

Comment: @SiderTopalov I've edited my question ! thank you

Comment: It is always a good habit to check your `$_POST[]` in your php by `isset()` and `!empty()`.

Answer (score 1):

Structure the `data` of your `$.ajax` request in a name-value pair manner.

Change this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '', //same page
    data: downloadURL ,
    success: function(data)
    {
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"downloadURL":downloadURL} ,
    success: function(data)
    {
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

I also removed `url` from your `$.ajax` request because [by default](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `url` is set to the current page.

With the above modifications, your PHP code will remain unchanged (e.g., `$user=$_POST['downloadURL'];`).

Answer (score 0):

Okay change your php with that code:

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadURL']) {
   $response = array(
        'user' => $_POST['downloadURL']
      );
      echo json_decode($response);
      exit;
  }
```

Because you are making **ajax request** you must return **json** that why we parse our Array to json(object) and then in your javascript ajax request inside success function write

```
console.log(data);
```

And after data

```
...
data: downloadUrl,
```

Add this

```
dataType: 'json'
```

This mean we are telling on our ajax request that we are expecting json response